# Unable to host my new website after addon domain in Cpanel

Tags: cpanel, public-html, addon-domain

I can't see my website after publishing it on the cpanel using file manager(public_html).

[image: Screen Shot]

My websites [Link](http://www.rusimbipatrick.rw) and afroark.org

Comment: Please can you share screen shot of your Cpanel domain manager

Comment: i have added the screenshot @Harshit_Raj

Comment: Sorry please can you select domain icon and then post the windows screen shot. https://imgur.com/a/uiGTKe4

Answer (score 0):

Try using file zilla to connect to ftp server and check for files.

or use file manager screen shot showing microsoft one drive.

can you please share more screen shot with some explanantion.